# Embolden parts of auto-complete suggestions that don't match the query

Tags: javascript, strings, autocomplete

I made a function to embolden text that doesn't match a string, but it appears to be very performance-heavy. I am certain that there are much better ways to do this, but with what I tried, I ran into a lot of trouble.

As a side note, one of the ways I know this is performance-heavy, is that when I type a few characters, and backspace them all, Chrome starts taking up more and more memory until it crashes.

Yes! I know this is not StackOverflow, so I'm just asking for some pointers on what the issues are with the code.

```
function Bolden(value, query) {
    var arr = []
    if (!value) return;
    while (value !== "") { // While the value still has work to be done on it
        if (value.toLowerCase().startsWith(query.toLowerCase())) {
            arr.push("<span style='font-weight: normal'>" + value.slice(0, query.length) + "</span>")
            value = value.slice(query.length, value.length)
        }
        else {
            arr.push(value.slice(0, 1))
            value = value.slice(1, value.length)
        }
    }
    return arr.join('')
}
```

Comment: could you add more context - e.g. how is `Bolden()` used? is it called once for each element in a list? if possible, provide sample HTML ...

Comment: It would take a lot of time for me to separate just the search box from everything else to be able to put here. Also, the search API it uses is only available on my company's domain.

Comment: Hmm ... I made [a sample on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a34uvnwc/9/) - could you fork it and update it to be closer to how it is actually used?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the current context available, if your `query` is not to be treated as a regex/custom pattern, I think a simple [`string.split`](https://devdocs.io/javascript/global_objects/string/split) should be enough. I am not that familiar with conventions in the JS world, but the last time I had worked with it, function names used to be in `camelCase`.

Also note that I am using [the template literals](https://devdocs.io/javascript/template_literals) when returning from `bolden` function; which should actually be named `unemphasize` (or `unbold` or `normaliser`).

```js
function bolden(value, query) {
  if (!value) return;
  let splt = value.split(query)
  return splt.join(`<span style="font-weight:normal">${query}</span>`)
}

let tests = new Map([
  ['some', 'e'],
  ['things', 'thi'],
  ['other', 'te'],
  ['looooooooong', 'o']
])

for (let [v, q] of tests)
  console.log(bolden(v, q))
```

Comment: This isn't case insensitive. Even if I were to call `toLowerCase` on `query`, it would replace capitalized matches with the lower case version.
Thanks!

Comment: `Bolden` is not defined in that snippet (since it was declared as `bolden`); While you mentioned template literals with a reference link, it might be wise to avoid using es-6 features like `let` unless the OP uses the tag [tag:ecmascript-6] or already has such features used; if you do use `let` it might be wise to only use it when re-assignment is necessary - otherwise use `const`